# How to set up method, which can delete only predefined value of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list and prepend() method in Jquery, every time when i click on this, i can append i new elemnts on html code. i can add even 1 000 000 times buit i want to have a limit. How can i set up limits ? For example, users when click on button, they should be able to append only 2 times.

html:

```
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn1">Prepend text</button>
<button id="btn2">Prepend list item</button>

</body>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("ol").prepend("<li>Prepended item</li>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something like this ?

```
var count = 0;
var limit = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("p").prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        if (count <= limit) {
            $("ol").prepend("<li>Prepended item</li>");
            count++;
        } else {
            alert('limit reached')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a data:

```
<button id="btn1" data-prepended="0">Prepend text</button>
```

And then

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    var a = parseInt($(this).data("prepended"),10);
    if(a<2){
    a++;
    $("p").prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
    $(this).data("prepended", a);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        if($('p>b').length<=2){
        $("p").prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
        }
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        if($('ol > li').length<5){
        $("ol").prepend("<li>Prepended item</li>");
        }
    });
});
```